# how does galil substring finding algorithm work

Tags: algorithm

I read the galil-seiferas algorithm mentioned in book Handbook of Exact StringMatching Algorithms by Christian Charras and Thierry Lecroq in chapter 28.
according to algorithm the string must be decomposed to two parts but in the example there's no partitioning i think i did't understand the algorithm can any one explain it to me or give and example or at least give a resource.i have to represent it and really need it.giving an example could be very helpful.
tnx

Comment: Can you post or link to the algorithm please?

Comment: here is the book http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string.pdf

Comment: any one? I realy need help.